# Populate multiple field values from php / sql response?

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I have the following HTML headers (h6 tags below) that I would like to populate from the result of my PHP / SQL query below. I have both of those components completed separately, but need to get the values from my PHP / SQL query into the h6 tags below. How would I accomplish this?

HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title m-b-40" >Company Name</h5>
    <h6 style='font-weight: bold;'>Company Overview</h6>
    <h6>Annual Revenue: 2,000,000,000</h6>
    <h6>Employees: 150,000</h6>
    <h6>Industry: xxx</h6>
    <h6>Inherent Risk Industry: xxx</h6>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $servername = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";

    $id = intval($_GET['id']); //casting to int type!

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        echo '<script>console.log("Connection successful!")</script>';
    }

    $SELECT2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `organization` WHERE organizationId=$id");

    if($SELECT2 != false)
    {

        while($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_array($SELECT2)){
    }

    }else{
        echo "
            <tr>
            <td colspan='3'>Something went wrong with the query</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
    <?php
```

Comment: Unless you're using AJAX, you need to put the HTML in your PHP script.

Comment: Can there really be multiple organizations with the same `organizationId`? Why do you need a `while` loop to process just one row?

Comment: What problem are you having putting the query results in the HTML? Just `echo "<h6>Employees: {$rows2['employees']}</h6>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can put the PHP and HTML on the same page, it would look like this:

```
<?php

$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo '<script>console.log("Connection successful!")</script>';
}

$SELECT2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `organization` WHERE organizationId=$id");

if($SELECT2 != false)
{
    $rows2 = $SELECT2->fetch_assoc();
}

}else{
    echo "
        <tr>
        <td colspan='3'>Something went wrong with the query</td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
?>

<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title m-b-40" ><?php echo $rows2['name']; ?></h5>
  <h6 style='font-weight: bold;'><?php echo $rows2['overview']; ?></h6>
  <h6>Annual Revenue: <?php echo $rows2['annual_revenue']; ?></h6>
  <h6>Employees: <?php echo $rows2['employees']; ?></h6>
  <h6>Industry: <?php echo $rows2['industry']; ?></h6>
  <h6>Inherent Risk Industry: <?php echo $rows2['risk']; ?></h6>
</div>
```

Note that the silly while loop is gone, since that query should only have one result, we're using fetch_assoc() to get an associative array instead of a numbered one so that you can use column names and keep this from being a human-unreadable mess, and we're just echoing the data where you need it in the html.  I am, of course, making assumptions about your column names.

If these can't be on the same page, you will need to make a request from the HTML page to your PHP script first and then do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Is this HTML a different page as the script? Because if that is the case, shouldn't you be able to just send this date from the script using GET variables to receive in the second page?

Assigned each field on the array to a variable and send them through http://example.com/yourpage.php?value1=$var1 etc etc